# Transpose Excel cell groups

Tags: excel, transpose

I have a structure that looks like the left side the image, which I am willing to turn in a structure that looks like the one on the right:

[image]

I could easily do that by individually copying and transpose pasting each question apart, but there are more than one thousand questions to copy. Is there a way to automate this action?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: does the number of elements {A,B,C,D} stay constant ?

Comment: not quite. part of them has ABCD+E as options. still figuring out how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

A VBA solution is fairly natural. The following sub gathers two 1-cell ranges from the user, the top cell of the original structure and the upper-left hand corner of the range where the data is to be put. It iterates over the source column, transferring the data to the target, with blank cells in the source column causing another row of data to be started in the target range:

```
Sub TransposeBlocks()
    Dim sourceColumn As Range, target As Range
    Dim A As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

    Set sourceColumn = Application.InputBox("Click the top cell in source data", , , , , , , 8)
    Set target = Application.InputBox("Click the corner of the target range", , , , , , , 8)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    A = Range(sourceColumn, Cells(Rows.Count(), sourceColumn.Column).End(xlUp)).Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(A)
        If Len(Trim(A(i, 1))) > 0 Then
            target.Offset(j, k).Value = A(i, 1)
            k = k + 1
        Else
            k = 0
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The above code assumes that a blank line separates each question block. If this assumption is false, it would be easy enough to tweak the code so that it looks for cells which match the pattern `Question*` and begin a new row in the target area whenever such a line is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using an `Indirect` if the number of elements stay constant.

```
=INDIRECT("A"&(ROW(C1))*6+COLUMN(C1)-7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without VBA, you could do this as follows [Assumes that each question has 4 values, you know the number of questions, the current data is all in column B, you want your new 'Question x' column in column D, and the values are text]:

In D1, put the following and drag down [either drag down the number of rows equal to your number of questions, or just drag down until there's an error]:

```
="Question "&ROW()
```

If you want the first question to be in row 2, you will need to adjust like this [or create a different method of iterating up by 1, such as using another helper column]:

```
="Question "&ROW()-1
```

Then in E1, where you have the first "A" above, put the following:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(D1,B:B,0)+1)
```

Then in F1, where you have the first "B" above, put the following:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(D1,B:B,0)+2)
```

Then in F1, where you have the first "C" above, put the following:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(D1,B:B,0)+3)
```

Then in F1, where you have the first "D" above, put the following:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(D1,B:B,0)+4)
```

What this does is search for the row # in column B which matches "Question x", where x = the row number used to create the ID in column D. Then it returns the value either 1 row below, 2 rows below, 3 rows below, or 4 rows below, which matches the pattern showing in your original data.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. But this works only if the value in B1 matches the one in D1. Which means I should have the question body somewhere else if I want to use this with drag n drop